# My report is not printing properly, what could be happening?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Greetings to the community.

I have the following report in Crystal-Reports using VB.NET and it comes out in "order" so to speak. Each account has its credit detail.

[image: foto1]

However, in this image I don't understand why it could be wrong. It is another report with other parameters, but the idea is still the same, only here it does not list the detail of each accounting account.

[image: foto2]

I am new to Crystal-Reports and I don't know where the error might be. I checked the following and everything is identical in both reports:

- Formulas.
- Section Wizard.

---

### EDIT (MORE DETAILS):

The report that is causing me problems has the following structure:

[image: imagen3]

However, I go by the report which is perfect and does not cause me any problems (practically a copy and paste):

[image: imagen4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the content of your Details section (or some other section) is "missing":

- Check it is not set to ***Hide (Drill-Down OK)***
- Check it is not set to ***Suppress*** (either directly or via an expression)

If that was not the issue, please clarify what content and in what section is not visible.

Comment: I have just added new information with more details about report structure.